# If I run my own minecraft server, will I have to pay for the clients?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-legacy-console

My family currently uses the XBox minecraft edition. I thought it would be a fun project to set up a minecraft server with my kids. I've got some hardware to run the server. I've downloaded the client software. When it starts up, it wants to update from some account.

Is it necessary to by a client to connect to my own server?

Perhaps another question: Do I have to buy a client for each computer I want to connect?

Answer (score 4):

Just get this one out of the way but I think you already know, the PC and XBox versions of the game are not compatible.

As for the simplified question, Yes. You should buy an account for each user to connect to the server. The server itself does not need an account and is a separate download from the client software though it is possible to 'Open to LAN' a single player world.